# mysql вывести группируя по полю

Tags: php, mysql

в таблице main есть записи,

```
id  title  type
1     q     1
2     qb    2
3     qbc   1
4     z     1
5     zb    2
6     zbc   3
```

как вывести их группируя по type, например

```
1

1   q
3   qbc

2

2   qb
5   zb
```

и т.д.

Comment: и что у вас не получается - вот так вывести, как вы показываете? сгруппировать?

Comment: да, я пробовал так select * from main group by type но выводит 3 записи

Comment: select type, group_concat(title) from main group by type . А дальше только ручками

Comment: да, первая колонка type, с id 4 я просто для примера скинул как выводить

Comment: если  group_concat(title) то он в это поле записывает все заголовки для каждого type

Comment: Какие нафиг "для примера"? показываемый вывод должен ТОЧНО соответствовать показанным исходным данным.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, title
FROM ( SELECT id, title, type
       FROM main
       UNION ALL
       SELECT DISTINCT type, NULL, type
       FROM main ) total
ORDER BY type, title IS NOT NULL, id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=452b6fe357c4aa68acce545a58bfd555)

Comment: SELECT type, title - вроде id хочет, а не type

Comment: @splash58 Да, точно... ща поправим. Готово вроде.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$tabl='test';
$query = "select * from ".$tabl."";
$result = $conn1->query($query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$arr[]=$row;
}

foreach ($arr as $key32 => $value32) {

$sar[$value32['type']]=$value32['title']; // ключь не может повторятся, поэтому можно сгрупировать

}
ksort($sar); //сортируем по возрастанию

echo'<table cellspacing="0" border="2" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 200px">'; // делаем красиво в таблицу
foreach ($sar as $key44 => $value44) {
  # code...
foreach($arr as $keywe => $valuew){

if($key44==$valuew['type']){
echo'<tr>';

echo '<td style="width: 100px;" align="center">'.$valuew['id'].'<td style="width: 100px;" align="center">'.$valuew['title'].'<td style="width: 100px;" align="center">'.$valuew['type'].'</td>';
echo'</tr>';
}}}
echo'</table>';
?>
```